# JavaScript does not work when I redirect control to another .erb file from mail .erb file. How should I make it work?

Tags: javascript, ruby, rhomobile

I am working RhoMobile app where I capture Lead details and throw Validation. On validation control goes to another .erb which generate Pop-up box to show list of errors..I have same code in both the .erb files but it does not work when validation occurs and control goes to new .erb. Please help me out in this.

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful for someone here, trying to help you. Give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you using the default jqueryMobile JavaScript library for your .erb files?